# SQL Script to import all views from another database using criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, view

Using SQL Server 2005. We have a master database which gets new views created from time to time, sometimes several times a day.

We have multiple customer databases which have the same table structure. I'd link to keep our customer's database views in sync with our master.

Currently we generate a SQL script from the master with all our views (they all start with !) with management studio. Then drop all the current views which start with an ! on the customer's databases and run the script on each.

I'd like to be able to just run a script which would drop all views starting with an ! and import all views from the master starting with an !.

I'd also like to not have to generate a new script each time a view gets created or updated.

Perhaps this is impossible to do with an sql script?

*edit - first part is done

Thanks to @Szymon for the initial part of the script which works fine, had to alter it a bit to accommodate sql2005 and some of the views having spaces in them

```
declare @sql as nvarchar(max)
set @sql = N''
select @sql = @sql + 'DROP VIEW "' + name + '";' from sys.views where name like '!%'
exec (@sql)
```

I've tried and I can't figure the second part out, sure it returns some (not all) view names with some values but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Have you tried scripting this with an external tool that can talk to multiple databases? SSIS, Powershell, or a C# applciation could all do this...

Comment: Hmm, I believe you but have no idea how to implement anything like that

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely doable. You can use the `sys` views to get all the necessary information.

For example, if you want drop all views that start with `!` in database `sample`, you can use:

```
declare @sql as nvarchar(max) = N''
select @sql = @sql + 'DROP VIEW ' + name + ';' from sample.sys.views where name like '!%'
exec (@sql)
```

In a similar way, you can use the following query to get the information to create views (this is just a sample, you may need more columns):

```
select v.name, c.name, t.name, c.max_length, c.is_nullable from sys.views v
inner join sys.columns c on v.object_id = c.object_id
inner join sys.types t on t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
```

This is not a complete solution but that should put you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The drop table part works well after altering it a bit. I'm plugging away at the hard part now.